# How to interpolate a specified number of generated values in a column in R?

Tags: r

I have a data with 78 observations in a column. I need to generate a column with 6400 observations. I thought I could interpolate value by value, but that will generate only one value between each of my original values.

Answer (score 2):

You can interpolate n values with `approx()`. Check documentation [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/approxfun.html)

small example:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
approx(x, n=100)
```

output:

```
  [1] 1.000000 1.030303 1.060606 1.090909 1.121212 1.151515 1.181818 1.212121 1.242424 1.272727 1.303030
 [12] 1.333333 1.363636 1.393939 1.424242 1.454545 1.484848 1.515152 1.545455 1.575758 1.606061 1.636364
 [23] 1.666667 1.696970 1.727273 1.757576 1.787879 1.818182 1.848485 1.878788 1.909091 1.939394 1.969697
 [34] 2.000000 2.030303 2.060606 2.090909 2.121212 2.151515 2.181818 2.212121 2.242424 2.272727 2.303030
 [45] 2.333333 2.363636 2.393939 2.424242 2.454545 2.484848 2.515152 2.545455 2.575758 2.606061 2.636364
 [56] 2.666667 2.696970 2.727273 2.757576 2.787879 2.818182 2.848485 2.878788 2.909091 2.939394 2.969697
 [67] 3.000000 3.030303 3.060606 3.090909 3.121212 3.151515 3.181818 3.212121 3.242424 3.272727 3.303030
 [78] 3.333333 3.363636 3.393939 3.424242 3.454545 3.484848 3.515152 3.545455 3.575758 3.606061 3.636364
 [89] 3.666667 3.696970 3.727273 3.757576 3.787879 3.818182 3.848485 3.878788 3.909091 3.939394 3.969697
[100] 4.000000
```

So just change it for your case like:

`approx(df$column, n=6400)`